# Read data from one file and write to multiple files

Tags: python, bash

I have a file that has large amount of data as shown below:

inputfile:

```
     MOLECULE=AMMONIA
     N                0.0000000000   0.0000000000  10.0000000000
     H                0.5883730000   0.5883730000  10.5883730000
     H               -0.5883730000  -0.5883730000  10.5883730000
     MOLECULE=AMMONIA
     N               -0.3476074320  -0.2347533040   9.3713354700
     H                0.2407655680   0.3536196960   9.9597084700
     H               -0.9359804320  -0.8231263040   9.9597084700
     MOLECULE=AMMONIA
     N               -1.2368117200  -0.5350340580   8.7012089080
     H               -0.6484387200   0.0533389420   9.2895819080
     H               -1.8251847200  -1.1234070580   9.2895819080
```

I need a bash script that reads all the lines from this file, and writes it to multiple output files like below:

outputfile1:

```
     MOLECULE=AMMONIA
     N                0.0000000000   0.0000000000  10.0000000000
     H                0.5883730000   0.5883730000  10.5883730000
     H               -0.5883730000  -0.5883730000  10.5883730000
```

outputfile2:

```
     MOLECULE=AMMONIA
     N               -0.3476074320  -0.2347533040   9.3713354700
     H                0.2407655680   0.3536196960   9.9597084700
     H               -0.9359804320  -0.8231263040   9.9597084700
```

outputfile3:

```
     MOLECULE=AMMONIA
     N               -1.2368117200  -0.5350340580   8.7012089080
     H               -0.6484387200   0.0533389420   9.2895819080
     H               -1.8251847200  -1.1234070580   9.2895819080
```

I tried readarray, but it stores everything in a 1-D array with now newline characters. Can you help me with a one-liner or a small script? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an "I can haz teh codez plz" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    i = 0
    f = open('outfile%d'%i, 'w')
    for line in infile:
        if line.lstrip().startswith("MOLECULE"):
            f.close()
            i += 1
            f = open('outfile%d'%i, 'w')
        f.write(line)
```